# IIS Express process keeps running and occupies a port (Cannot kill it), Restart machine is the only option

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

i have a site that runs on a specific port on IIS Express, I cannot stop the process from task bar - even as administrator.

When i stop it from it's console, it seems i cannot connect to the site anymore, the IIS express console doesn't remove the site, and the port stays occupied.

If i try to start again the site, i get "Access is denied" and "Port X is in use".

Only restart works for me.

[image: Issue]

This is the project's configuration:

[image]

Anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Quite old post, but... Same problem here. Inspected the process with Sysinternals and it tells me it's hidden... Can't kill it. Have you solved it?